# Compact bash function using || operator to retry command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to produce a very compact version of a function similar to Travis CI's [`travis_retry`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/9ec05b37295a6d9e8e5e06f99b59f878b2176b40/lib/travis/build/bash/travis_retry.bash).
The function should basically be a higher order function, trying the provided arguments as command for three times, and failing (return 1) in case of repeated failure.

Here are some attempts I've made, none of them worked as I expected:

```bsh
retry() {
    "${@}" || "${@}" || "${@}"
}
```

This seemingly works for simple commands (like `echo ciao`), but fails for any non trivial expression:

```bsh
$ retry if true; then echo hello; fi; false
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

I would have expected the function to print `hello` three times and return `1` (due to `false` being evaluated last).

A second attempt is the following:

```bsh
retry() {
    $* || $* || $*
}
```

which seems to behave just like the previous one.
I also tried a third version with `eval`, but of course it's not working: at this point it's clear that I'm missing some basics here and I'd like to understand rather than keep attempting.

Comment: The `;` line break is being evaluated on the command line so you are executing `retry if true` and then as an entirely separate command trying to execute `then echo hello`

Comment: You are likely to want to `eval` the passed-in code if you're expecting to be able to work with compound commands.

Comment: You are both right! I'm trying now with `retry() { eval "$*" || eval "$*" || eval "$*"; }`, also correctly escaping and invoking as `retry "if true; then echo ciao; fi; false"`, it seeems to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a function, you could only pass a number of string arguments, so that could only be interpreted as a the argument of a simple command. You could pass arbitrary shell code as one string, but that code would have to be evaluated and you'd have to quote it so it's passed as one literal string to the function.

```
retry() { eval " $1" || eval " $1" || eval " $1"; }
retry 'if true; then echo hello; fi; false'
```

Or your:

```
retry() { "$@" || "$@" || "$@"; }
```

called as:

```
retry eval 'if true; then echo hello; fi; false'
```

Using aliases, you could however do something like:

```
alias 'retry{{={
  attempts=0
  until {' '}}=
  }; do
    if (( ++attempts >= 3 )); then
      echo >&2 "Giving up after $attempts attempts"
      ! break
    fi
  done
}'
```

And then:

```
bash-5.0$ retry{{ echo test; false; }}
test
test
test
Giving up after 3 attempts
```

That works because aliases are expanded upon reading code before it's fully parsed, a bit like preprocessor macros in C.

Comment: Oh dear that alias... That looks like one of those things where it's hard to say if it's a brilliant hack, or an unearthly abomination. Same as a lot of things that can be done with the C preprocessor, like the `#define BEGIN {` stuff etc. (did some early shell use that?)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use the retry command rather than bash first principles.

Here we retry a non trivial expression designed to fail each time, giving up after three attempts.

```
~$ ./retry --times 3 -- sh -c "echo hello; echo there; false"
hello
there
retry: sh returned 1, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
hello
there
retry: sh returned 1, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
hello
there
retry: sh returned 1, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
```

https://github.com/minfrin/retry

Available out the box in recent Debian, Ubuntu, and Nix.